# How to keep track of and display uploaded images after uploading?

Tags: php, image, file-upload

I made a little page where you can upload picture it is simple php upload. I want everyone to be able to upload images and view everyone else's uploads on the site. How can I display images after they're uploaded? I want to be able to globally track all uploaded images so that everyone can browse them.

I think I need to use "AJAX upload" to do that and maybe javascript to display image after upload... but how?

I tried this:

```
function GetFileName(){

            var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileToUpload');
            var fileName = fileInput.value.split(/(\\|\/)/g).pop();

            var img = document.createElement('img');
            img.src = 'uploads/' + fileName;
            img.setAttribute('width', '100px');
            img.setAttribute('height', '100px');
            img.alt = fileName;         
            document.body.appendChild(img);
            alert(fileName);
        }




<form method="post" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload" class="upload">
            <input type="submit" onclick="GetFileName()" value="Upload Image" name="submit" id="submit">
</form>
```

This is almost work but the image only display few second and then it disappear.

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this in Jquery:

```
$('#upload').on('click', function() {
    var img_name  = $('#pic').val();
    var file_data = $('#pic').prop('files')[0];
    var form_data = new FormData();
    form_data.append('file', file_data);

    $.ajax({
            url         : 'upload.php',     // point to server-side PHP script 
            dataType    : 'text',           // what to expect back from the PHP script, if anything
            cache       : false,
            contentType : false,
            processData : false,
            data        : form_data,                         
            type        : 'post',
            success     : function(output){
                if(output)  // if success
                {
                    $('#img_container').append('<img src="img_path/"'+ img_name +'>');  // It will display the uploaded image
                }
            }
     });
     $('#pic').val('');                     /* Clear the file container */
});
```

Html:

```
<body>
<input id="pic" type="file" name="pic" />
<button id="upload">Upload</button>

<!-- To display image -->
<div id="img_container">

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the key issue to your question here is in how to keep track of all the uploads. This is likely better solved by relying on a persistence store, like a database, to track of all uploaded files on a global level.

For example, when an upload occurs, you can insert a record into an `uploads` table in your database like so...

```
// prepare the statement
$stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO uploads (userId, fileName) VALUES(:userId, :fileName)");

if ($_FILES['upload']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) { // no errors
    // move the file to a permanent location
    $tmpName = $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $uploadDir . "/$tmp_name");
    $result = $stmt->execute(
        [
            'userId'   => $_SESSION['userId'], // or however you track the user
            'fileName' => $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'],
        ]
    );
    if ($result) {
        // record added successfully! 
    } else {
        // failed
    }
}
```

Now you can display all uploaded files by looking at the `uploads` table in your database and display them to users like so...

```
// prepare the statement
$start = $_GET['start'] ?? 0;
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT userId, fileName FROM uploads LIMIT ?,20");
if ($stmt->execute([$start])) {
    $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach($result as $row) {
        echo "<img src='$uploadDir/{$row['fileName']}'>";
    }
}
```

Or you could show only those uploads made by a specific user by adding a `WHERE userId = ?` clause to that query, for example.